# How to Create Session mode in asp.net & c# , User in Sql Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, session

How to Create Session using c# and Sql Server

Comment: I strongly suspect that MSDN contains answer, but I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: You need more detail in your question; what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net already provides a `Session` that you can use for all session management.
It also provides a mode that allows you to store the session in SQL server.

```
<sessionState 
            mode="SQLServer"
            sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>"
            cookieless="false" 
            timeout="20" 
    />
```

Refer: [HOW TO: Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Comment: not stored the session in SQL server
I want to come with username and password and permission to display the page from the database and then works its session
And how the work of the session of the Page

Comment: Didn't quite get your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
int flag=1;    
da=new SqlDataAdapter("select uname,password from tlbLogin where uname='"+txtName.Text+"' AND pASSWORD='"+TXTpASSWARD.tEXT+"'",conn);
dataset ds=new dataset();
da.fill(ds);
  if(ds.tables[0].rows.count>0)
   {
     Session("sessionName")=txtName.text;
      responce.redirect("mainPage.aspx");
   }
```

**Session Syntax:**

```
Session("sessionName")=sessionvalue;
```

This is the syntax for creating session.

You can refer this to learn more about it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Comment: I want to come with username and password and permission to display the page from the database and then works its session
And how the work of the session of the Page

Comment: @htomyy check my edited code if its helpful.

Comment: Getting +1 back... If you want to show "select * where name=@username" please don't iterate through elements yourself - SQL is perfectly fine to do that. Also make sure to add correct hashing of password.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you are right, check my edited answer and tell me if its correct way.

Comment: Are you trying to get -1 as you don't have downvotes yet on this question :) ? SQL injection is much worse than code before... Maybe you should simply suggest table structure and link of SQLCommand... Without proper comment on "do not store password in database, only properly hashed value based on password" such answer on creation of user table would not deserve +1.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Its not about +1 but about right operation and right way to do it. If you know correct way you can edit my answer as you want. I have sufficient reputation, 10 points will not make much difference to me.

Comment: I'm not that serios about points :). The problem is your code demonstrates how *not to* write SQL statements - it contains most classic case of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) which is bad for public samples. If you are indeed writing code this way - please consider using parametrized queries. And here is mandatory link to "Bobby Tables" - http://www.xkcd.com/327/ :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanx. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection was helpful. espacially 1;drop tablename; now i came to understand the importance of parametrized queries

Comment: @htomyy welcome. If helpful. Accept it.